# Been trying to overlap these two images but I keep getting a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to get this work for a very long time but I couldn't seem to get it to work. I tried to import Image as well but canopy couldn't name the module Image. I really need some help with this one. Someone help me please, I'm so stuck right now.

```
    import PIL
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import os.path  
    import PIL.ImageDraw  


    def get_images(directory=None):

        if directory == None:
            directory = os.getcwd() # Use working directory if unspecified

        image_list = [] # Initialize aggregaotrs
        file_list = []

        directory_list = os.listdir(directory) # Get list of files
        for entry in directory_list:
            absolute_filename = os.path.join(directory, entry)
            try:
                image = PIL.Image.open(absolute_filename)
                file_list += [entry]
                image_list += [image]
            except IOError:
                pass # do nothing with errors tying to open non-images
        return image_list, file_list


    def ben(x_range=None):
        background = PIL.Image.open("funland.jpg")
        overlay = PIL.Image.open("shivam2.jpg")

        background = background.convert("RGBA")
        overlay = overlay.convert("RGBA")

        background_pixels = background.load()
        overlay_pixels = overlay.load()

        if x_range == None:
            for y in x_range(overlay.size[1]):
                for x in x_range(overlay.size[0]):
                    background_pixels[x,y] = (background_pixels[x,y][0], background_pixels[x,y][1], background_pixels[x,y][2], 255)
        if x_range == None:
            for y in x_range(overlay.size[1]):
                for x in x_range(overlay.size[0]):
                    overlay_pixels[x,y] = (overlay_pixels[x,y][0], overlay_pixels[x,y][1], overlay_pixels[x,y][2], 128)

        new_img = PIL.Image.blend(background, overlay, 0.5)
        new_img.save("new.png","PNG")
```

Comment: It would help to include also the traceback that you get from your Python interpreter, or at least the line number where it errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in these two lines:

```
if x_range == None:
        for y in x_range(overlay.size[1]):
```

First, you check if the range is a `None` object, then you try to call it with `(overlay.size[1])`. I guess you meant `x_range != None`?